# Changing order of numbers in a simple math operation yields different result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
print((1199/1070)*1070)
```

returns: 1198.9999999999998

```py
print((1070/1070)*1199)
```

returns 1199.0

how to overcome this behavior ?
( Python version == 3.8.3 )

Comment: it's a result of order of operations and float math calculations. How to overcome - depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: as @buran said it's a result of floating point arithmetic and you can read more about it in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html . If the numbers are small you usually can overcome this by first multiplying and then dividing but it really depends on the situation.

Comment: @NuLo i cannot change the order actually. i need to first calculate a ratio and then multiply it by a number. these number and ratio come from different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by floating point numbers being in binary, making fractions with a denominator of anything other than a power of 2 only approximate.

To fix this, you can use the built-in `fractions` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(float(Fraction(1199)/1070*1070)) # prints: 1199.0
print(float(Fraction(1070)/1070*1199)) # prints: 1199.0
```

This will be slower than floating point operations, but will not have any errors from numbers that are unrepresentable in binary floating point in a finite amount of space.

Comment: Thank you , but shouldn't it be like : print(float(Fraction(1199,1070)*1070))

Comment: @SaeidMohammadiNejati those are equivalent, Fraction overrides the operators. You are using a Fraction object all the way until the conversion to float hence the performance penalty.